# Flutter FCM on android problem: repeat message everytime app open

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im having an issue that I keep receiving the same FCM message every-time the app opens by the onmessage listener. Somehow its keeps coming back and not consumed. This is a communication to one device use-case using push notifications from one device to another.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.